# Maximum number of dimensions in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = array(array(array(array(array()))));
```

The above example shows an array with five dimensions.

Is there a maximum number of dimensions allowed in a PHP array? If so, what is that maximum?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089230/multidimensional-array-size-limit-in-php

Comment: See: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467149/what-is-the-max-key-size-for-an-array-in-php][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467149/what-is-the-max-key-size-for-an-array-in-php

Comment: build a crazy loop and test it :-)

Comment: And possibly also relevant: [A Closer Look Into PHP Arrays: What You Don’t See](https://sheriframadan.com/2012/10/a-closer-look-into-php-arrays/)

Comment: Create a custom function as defined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262891/is-there-a-way-to-find-how-how-deep-a-php-array-is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `array` level generally costs you `304` bytes (determined by checking memory usage, creating an array, then checking again), and the total amount of memory can be calculated using `ini_get("memory_limit")`.  To get the current usage, run `memory_get_usage()`.

On my computer:

- `ini_get("memory_limit")` returns `"128M"`, or `134217728` bytes.
- `memory_get_usage()` base use is `627120`

so I would expect the limit on my kit to be `439442` depth

Answer (score 1):

It's about memory limit. Try it yourself.

```
$array = array();
$temp_array = &$array;
while (true)
    $temp_array = &$temp_array[0];
```