# PHP in_array comparison working differently on different machine

Tags: php, arrays

Please review following piece of code, it is giving different results on different machines:

```
$data = array(
    "28000000000000003" => 'ABC',
    "28000000000000001" => 'PQR'
);

echo "1.".in_array("28000000000000003",array_keys($data),true);

echo "2.".in_array("28000000000000003",array_keys($data));

echo "3.".in_array("28000000000000003",array("28000000000000003","28000000000000001"),true);

echo "4.".in_array("28000000000000003",array("28000000000000003","28000000000000001"));
```

As expected, results true for all 4 cases on our local server, while on production server in 1st case it is giving false result and true in rest of three

Can anybody help me to understand what exactly happening? Do I missed from configuration point of view?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about the fact that these are strings?

Comment: Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If that numbers are *not* strings, but ints it will give different results

Comment: Yes,This is real case copied from working file which is generating this in consistent result

Comment: do `array_map('var_dump',  array_keys($data));`

Comment: array_map('var_dump', array_keys($data)); Local it is giving the following 

string(17) "28000000000000003"
string(17) "28000000000000001"

on production the following

int(28000000000000003)
int(28000000000000001)

Comment: So there's your answer :) How are you creating that array on production?

Comment: following the code how it is declared

$data=array(
  "28000000000000003" => 'ABC',
  "28000000000000001" => 'PQR',
);
   
array_map('var_dump', array_keys($data));

this is same code running on both servers

Comment: Does the production machine use 64-bit version of PHP?

Comment: Yes I am confident, I have double checked all things, actually I am facing problem in real file, so to duplicate the issue I have made one test file in I am testing pseudo code to try different test cases, so this test file has exactly given code nothing else...

Comment: [it seems related to this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php#105578), so use the 3rd argument on array_keys (strict)

Comment: I have server os surely 64bits and local 32bits

Comment: bool(true), bool(true), bool(true), bool(true) testing on 64bit

Comment: Hmmm, anyone have any idea if this is a documented bug or 'expected' behavior? Seems like deciding to randomly convert to ints in a "strict" comparison is silly. Screams PHP-core bug to me unless it's already been documented and PHP decided that it's a 'feature'. I've searched for a bug report, and tried to find something in the docs about this, but can't find anything.

Comment: See below for a simple workaround ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its very easy .... let me guess your Development system is windows and your production server is linux ?

You are having Integer overflow Issues because most likey your windows version of PHP is 32bit and linux is 64bit

[See Condition for array key conversion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

- Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.
- Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8.
- Bools are cast to integers, too, i.e. the key true will actually be stored under 1 and the key false under 0.
- Null will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key null will actually be stored under "".
  Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.

So what happens is that :

So the key `28000000000000003` is a valid `integer` on a `64bit` but a `String` on a `32bits` system

[I was able to replicate your issue](http://codepad.viper-7.com/P1AYGn)

```
echo "<pre>";
$data = array("28000000000000003" => 'ABC',"28000000000000001" => 'PQR');
$keys = array("28000000000000003","28000000000000001");
$keysDerived = array_keys($data);

var_dump(in_array("28000000000000003", $keysDerived, true));
var_dump(in_array("28000000000000003", $keysDerived));
var_dump(in_array("28000000000000003", $keys, true));
var_dump(in_array("28000000000000003", $keys));
```

[Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/P1AYGn)

```
bool(false)    <----------------------- false instead of true 
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

This issues has nothing to do with `in_array` but rather `array_keys` example

[**Sample Code**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mDrGjb)

```
echo "<pre>"; 
$data = array("28000000000000003" => 'ABC',"28000000000000001" => 'PQR');
$keys = array("28000000000000003","28000000000000001");
$keysDerived = array_keys($data);
var_dump($keys,$keysDerived);
```

[**Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mDrGjb)

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "28000000000000003"    <------- Keys are String
  [1]=>
  string(17) "28000000000000001"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(28000000000000003)           <------- They are converted to int on 64bits
  [1]=>
  int(28000000000000001)
}
```

[See Online Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mDrGjb)

This means that they are not the same type ...

> [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)   bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
>
> If the third parameter **strict** is set to **TRUE** then the in_array() function will also check the **types of the needle in the haystack**.

**[If you run this code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Qtq53x)**

```
foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
    echo gettype($key) . "\n";
}

foreach ( $keysDerived as $key ) {
    echo gettype($key) . "\n";
}
```

[Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Qtq53x) 64Bits

```
string
string
integer
integer
```

Output 32Bits

```
string
string
string
string
```

[**Simple Workaround**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AwJlzn)

```
echo "<pre>";
$data = array("28000000000000003" => 'ABC',"28000000000000001" => 'PQR');
$keys = array("28000000000000003","28000000000000001");
$keysDerived = array_keys_string($data);
var_dump($keys,$keysDerived);

var_dump(in_array("28000000000000003", $keysDerived, true));
var_dump(in_array("28000000000000003", $keysDerived));
var_dump(in_array("28000000000000003", $keys, true));
var_dump(in_array("28000000000000003", $keys));
```

[Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AwJlzn)

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "28000000000000003"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "28000000000000001"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "28000000000000003"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "28000000000000001"
}
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

[See Original Code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jMErED)
[See Modified Code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AwJlzn)

Function Used

```
function array_keys_string(array $input) {
    $list = array();
    foreach ( $input as $k => $v ) {
        $list[] = (string)$k;
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your local server is 32-bit and your production server is 64-bit.

[PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) says that when defining array literals, keys will be cast:

> Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8.

So, if you try the following piece of code:

```
var_export(array("5" => "test"));
```

You will see the result is an array with numerical key `5`, not string key `"5"`.

In your case, you have large numerical strings as keys. On a 32-bit machine, number `28000000000000003` exceeds the maximum possible integer value (`PHP_INT_MAX`), so the array key will stay string, and that is what happens on your local server. On a 64-bit machine, on the other hand, maximum integer is way greater, and `"28000000000000003"` is cast to `integer`, and that is what happens on your production server.

So, when run on the 64-bit production server, `array_keys($data)` returns array of integers. When in your first test case you try to find a string in it using strict comparison, you get `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `array_key_exists()` . associative array keys has some limitation in length. see the link for details help [PHP associative array's keys (indexes) limitations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496612/php-associative-arrays-keys-indexes-limitations)

You can increase your key memory limit. use `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');`

Comment: Nothing in his question describes any behavior that would be indicative of hitting a memory limit. Additionally, in the big scheme of things, his array keys are relatively short. This answer doesn't seem to address his question.

Answer (score 2):

**Issue** : If you have keys that are long integer, such as '329462291595', they will be considered **as such** on a 64bits system, but will be of type **string** on a 32 bits system.

So the function `array_keys($data)` will return int in 64 bit system and string in 32 bit system

**Solution** : convert all `array_keys($data)` to string.
           and then `in_array("28000000000000003",array_keys($data),true);` with third parameter `true` (for strict check)

```
function array_keys_string($arr){
    $arr_keys      = array_keys($arr);
    $res_arry      = array();
    foreach($arr_keys as $val){
       $res_arry[] = (string)$val;
    }
    return $res_arry;
}


echo "1.".in_array("28000000000000003",array_keys_string($data),true);
```

this will give you same result in both the servers.

**Refer following links** :

ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php#105578

From php.net : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
<?php
$a = array('1.10', 12.4, 1.13);

if (in_array('12.4', $a, true)) {
    echo "'12.4' found with strict check\n";
}

if (in_array(1.13, $a, true)) {
    echo "1.13 found with strict check\n";
}
?>
```

The above example will output: 1.13 found with strict check

Comment: No. On a 32-bit platform, `array_keys($data)` will contain strings, whilst `28000000000000003` without quotes [will be converted to float](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow), so the result of `in_array` with strict compatison will be `FALSE`.