# Is php/js object reliable when collision occureed? How to test it?

Tags: javascript, php, hashmap

Object and asscoiative array in php/js is hash map,

so I worry about the reliability if I store many elements in an array.

I worry data will be overwritten when collision occureed.

What hash is used in php/js, and how to find two collision string to test it?

Comment: If you can easily find the strings which collide, then the hash function is obviously weak :p

Comment: There will always be collisions in a hash map - that's when you start establishing buckets and do some kind of search through the bucket. You don't have to worry about "losing" data if two keys' hashes happen to collide. the underlying systems will ensure that those two keys' values will still be asssigned to separate storage

Comment: If two keys have same hash, how the system knows the values should assign to separate storage or same storage? and how to locate the correct value if a given key hash two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] the array's internal hashing mechanism will convert your string
>   to an integer it can then use to address a bucket within the array.
>   PHP's arrays aren't true/real arrays - they are some sort of Linked
>   HashMap internally. Considering that multiple strings can boild down
>   to the same hash, each bucket is a list itself. If there are multiple
>   elements within the same bucket, each key has to be evaluated.

Extracted from [PHP associative array's keys (indexes) limitations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9496780/959819) ([rodneyrehm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515124/rodneyrehm) answer)