# Adding a timestamp as a key in an array

Tags: php

I am trying to set use a timestamp as a key for an array as shown below.

```
    $interval = isset($this->data->interval)?$this->data->interval:(86400000); // default interval is one day
    $curstime = isset($this->data->stime)?$this->data->stime:(strtotime('-1 week')*1000);
    $curetime = $curstime + $interval;
    $stopetime = isset($this->data->etime)?$this->data->etime:(time()*1000);
    $graph = [];
    while ($curstime<=$stopetime){
        switch($graphtype){
            case 1: $tempstats=$stats->getOverviewStats($result);
               break;
            case 2: $tempstats=$stats->getCountTakingsStats($result);
               break;
        }
        if ($tempstats['error']=="OK"){
            $graph[$curstime] = $tempstats['data'];
       }
```

The key, `$curstime` is different from what is in the variable, but the issue is only on windows. This is the output when I log the value of `$curstime`.

```
1509310800727
```

and this is the output of logging `$graph`.

```
(
    [1777279831] => stdClass Object
        (
            [saletotal] => 0.00
            [salenum] => 0
            [refundtotal] => 0.00
            [refundnum] => 0
            [voidtotal] => 0.00
            [voidnum] => 0
            [salerefs] => 
            [voidrefs] => 
            [refundrefs] => 
            [totaltakings] => 0
            [cost] => 0
            [profit] => 0
            [refs] => 
        )

)
```

I expect `1509310800727` to the key instead of `1777279831`. What is causing the difference and how can I fix this?

Comment: You have o conditional in interval, this certainly is not the best way, as depending on the value it will affect the key generated. One thing, your provided timestamp has something very wrong, convertindo to date we get:
27/04/2026 08:50 and 26/02/49798 00:12

Year 49798? Could you give us some inputs that you are receiving to verify?

Comment: Key size might be the problem ?  Just check out the below link for more information.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496612/php-associative-arrays-keys-indexes-limitations

Comment: There is `$curstime+=$interval;
            $curetime+=$interval;` to increment the inverval. The timestamp is okay, try https://www.epochconverter.com/ am using it confirm the value. @Marco