# Are there size limits to PHP array keys? What are the limits in general for PHP arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the max key size for an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467149/what-is-the-max-key-size-for-an-array-in-php)

As the title says, I'm wondering what are the limits to PHP's arrays?

1. What are the limits to array keys?
2. Can I use any size string as the key?
3. At what point will keys start to collide? 
   What I mean here is, I thought PHP arrays were hashtables. My understanding of hashtables and their hash functions are that at some point two strings can hash to the same value, giving you a collision. For example MD5 was found to not be collision resistant.
4. What is the size limit to a php array?

Comment: Even if there is a limit to the key, it's nothing you should ever reach.

Comment: @Truth I was thinking of writing a web crawler in PHP and these questions popped into my head. I was thinking of using the URLs as keys to prevent duplicate entries and to prevent the crawler from looping on a page.

Answer (score 7):

1. **What are the limits to array keys?**

   There is no theoretical limits more then the size of memory allocated to the script. You can also find a proof at [What is the max key size for an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467149/what-is-the-max-key-size-for-an-array-in-php)

   The php manual says [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php);

   > Note: It is no problem for a string to become very large. PHP imposes no boundary on the size of a string; the only limit is the available memory of the computer on which PHP is running.

   This matters since the keys in a array can be strings.
2. **Can I use any size string as the key?**

   Yes, depending on the amount of memory allocated for the script. You can set the size by starting you script with for example `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` this set amount of memory to one gigabyte. To set the memory limit to unlimited use `-1`.

   *BUT* when the size of the keys grows you will need more power to work with the array.
3. **At what point will keys start to collide?**

   (I do not now if I understod the questions property)If you use all the combinations of letters and numbers up to a infinity long string, there will be infinity numbers of combinations. And therefor they will never collide.
4. **What is the size limit to a php array?**

   It is limited in the same way as above, by the amount of memory allocated for the script.